# HQL - Return a List of Complex Objects

Tags: java, hql

Currently have 2 very basic Classes, one is nested in the other one.

Class Job:

```
public Class Job {
   private String name;
   private int salary;
   ... // Basic Constructors + Getters/Setters
}
```

Class Company:

```
public Class Company {
   private String name;
   private Collection<Job> jobs;
   ... // Basic Constructors + Getters/Setters
}
```

You probably guessed it, trying to make a query that will return a list of Companies that each contain their Collection of Jobs.

The query:

```
select COMPANY_NAME, JOB_NAME, count(*) FROM COMPANY_REPORT cr, JOB_DECLARATIONS jd
where cr.COMPANY_NAME = jd.COMPANY_NAME
group by cr.COMPANY_NAME , cr.JOB_NAME
order by cr.COMPANY_NAME , cr.JOB_NAME
```

Will return something like this:

```
Company Name | Job Name | Count
--------------------------------
Soni           Assistant    3
Soni           Manager      1
Zoom           Potographer  5
```

But I can't seem to understand the HQL syntax for it.

```
Select new com.stuff.Company(cr.COMPANY_NAME, ...how to add collection??) FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  c.name, j.name, count(*) from company c, job j where c.name=:name    group by c.name, c.jobs
Order by c.name,c.jobs
```

find setparameterList [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29)